# Is it trivial to add a directory to a Joomla site that shouldn't interact with Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

I realise this is a trivial question but I don't have access to a Joomla installation to test.

I have to write some code that does a bunch of background processing, talks to web services etc and does not relate whatsoever to the Joomla CMS used by this existing site. I know Joomla does a bunch of URL rewriting, what I want to know is if I stash my processing code in say {domain}/tools how easy is it to tell Joomla not to do anything with that? Is it just a matter of adding a rule to .HTACCESS to avoid that directory, or does Joomla spider it and play with its files?

Bare in mind my experience with Joomla is near 0 (I've used it only to maintain some articles on various sites previously) and I'm not doing Joomla work, my stuff just needs to coexist with Joomla on this server.

Comment: Ask yourself this question, Do you need the a directory that shouldn't interact with joomla? IF the answer is yes. `of course`

Comment: I know it's going to be possible, I just need to know how trivial it is given this isn't my server and I don't have access to it.

Comment: IF you need it and dont have access to it, you should ask the hosting provider or whm or similar for the permission.

Comment: I see this as a fairly trivial question, I need to tell their programmer what to do with my PHP files when I deliver them. I am subcontracted to do this.

Comment: the answer is yes, you can put your code under [joomla home]/tools/ and use it. Joomla shouldn't have any problem with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joomla! can co-exist with other systems quite easily the main consideration is the way the standard Joomla! `.htaccess` file (if enabled) remaps everything through the /index.php file for SEO purposes.

However, it shouldn't cause you any issues as the `.htaccess` file is not supposed to rewrite the request if a real file exists at the request path.

```
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

If the `.htaccess` catches your `/tools/` example then yes you would have to modify the default configuration.

(For completeness, Joomla! also ships with a web.config file for MS servers that does a similar remapping of requests).